# A.P series. Find the value of the first installment.

Tags: combinatorics

A man arranges to pay of a debt of Ksh$3600$ in $40$ annual installments which form an A.P series. When $30$ of the installments are paid, he dies leaving one third of the debt unpaid. Find the value of the first installment.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Sum of first 30 terms of the AP is 2400. Sum of the first 40 terms is 3600. Just equate the equations you can form from the Sum of x terms of an AP formula.

Comment: thanks ,,,,,,,,